# canvas js delay or wait() before running the following code

Tags: canvasjs, animate-cc

I have been trying to find a way of delaying the running for the JS code in a HTML canvas document. I know how it is done with TweenJS see below:

I know how it is done with TweenJS see below:

`createjs.Tween.get(this.movieClip).wait(200).to({scaleX:1.10,scaleY:1.10}, 100, createjs.Ease.quadOut);`

But I want to delay or wait in running the following code instead of waiting on a tween:

`this.movieClip.gotoAndPlay("frameName");`

Answer (score 0):

With help from JoãoCésar
Use the setTimeout method.

```js
var root = this;  
setTimeout(function()  
{  
    root.movieClip.gotoAndPlay("frameName");  
}, 200);
```